# How to pass a Bitmap from an Activity to an other in a fast way?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap

I'm trying to pass a Bitmap from an Activity to an other, I tried multiple solutions but they are not fast enough.

Currently I'm facing this problem: When I click the next button it freezes for 2 seconds then move to the next Activity with the right Bitmap shown in the ImageView.

I found this solution in StackoverFlow. Here is the code:

```
  Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra("URI");
        if (imageUri != null) {
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No image is set to show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

  btn_next_process.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (bitmap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(CropResultActivity.this, "Emptyyy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                try {
                    //Write file
                    String filename = "bitmap.png";
                    FileOutputStream stream = CropResultActivity.this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                    //Cleanup
                    stream.close();
                  //  bitmap.recycle();

                    //Pop intent
                    Intent in1 = new Intent(CropResultActivity.this, InputProcessingActivity.class);
                    in1.putExtra("image_data", filename);
                    startActivity(in1);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Then I tried to save the file in a worker Thread first, and when I click the next button I retrieve it, now it's working fast but I am getting a wrong Bitmap.

Here is the code :

```
  Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra("URI");
        if (imageUri != null) {
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //Write file
                            FileOutputStream stream = CropResultActivity.this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                            //Cleanup
                            stream.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }.run();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No image is set to show", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

  btn_next_process.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (bitmap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(CropResultActivity.this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                //Pop intent
                Intent in1 = new Intent(CropResultActivity.this, InputProcessingActivity.class);
                in1.putExtra("image_data", filename);
                startActivity(in1);
            }
        }
    });
```

In the second Activity I retrieve the Bitmap this way :

```
  private void getIncomingIntent(){
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("image_data")){
        try {
            String filename = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_data");
            FileInputStream is = this.openFileInput(filename);
            imageToProcess = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            process_detect_edges(imageToProcess);
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bitmaps are also Parcelable. Why not pass it directly through the Intent?

Comment: I've read that if you pass the hole Bitmap in intent,as the size increase you will get "java.lang.SecurityException" and it's not best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the image uri to next activity. Load from the uri in other activity.

Comment: I will try your solution and keep you updated. Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Happy to help.

Comment: I'm sorry for posting an incomplete piece of code, but I wasn't setting the image from the Uri, actually it was an if else statement.So I tried converting the Bitmap in the first Activity to byteArray and I've got a TransactionTooLargeException. Then I tried using a static variable in the second Activity and now it's working like a charm. Excuse my long update.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a trivial `Service`. Give that `Service` a `public Bitmap mBitmap` member.
2. Keep each `Activity` bound to the `Service` while they are between `onStart()` and `onStop()`.
3. If your `Activities` have a reference to the `Service`, they can communicate directly via the `mBitmap` member. One `Activity` can set `mBitmap`, then start the other `Activity`. The second `Activity` can simply grab the reference (after binding, of course), and begin manipulating the `Bitmap`. Since everything happens on the UI thread, there are no synchronization concerns. And everything is quite fast.

This solution does not address problems of persistence: If the user leaves the app for a period of time (puts it the background, locks the screen, etc.), then the entire app may be destroyed, and `mBitmap` would be lost. However, if you're just trying to share data between two successive `Activities`, this is a straightforward way of doing it.

You could even share the `Bitmap` via a `public static` reference, placed in any convenient class. There are rumors that the garbage collector goes around setting `static` references to `null` at a whim, but this is a misinterpretation of the actual behavior: That an entire app may get cleaned up at an unexpected time. When you return to your `Activity`, the system may actually have to restart the app and recreate the `Activity` from scratch. In this case, the reference would be reset to `null`.

Instead, using a `Service` indicates to the OS that you have a component of your app that should be a little bit longer-lived. Certainly, it will continue to exist across the gap between two successive `Activities`.

Note that, on Oreo and later, the system can be quite aggressive about cleaning up apps as soon as they leave the foreground.

Comment: I really appreciate your solution and I think it's the proper one to use.
What do you think about using enums ?

Comment: Enums? You lost me.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I mean using enum with static method to set and get a Bitmap in my target Avtivity. I think using enum will eliminate the need to use singleton reference and reference is always deleted after my activity receives it.

Comment: I don't really object to the use of static references, but I don't see how an enum would be useful or even relevant. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: Enum is value type variable, so it is automatically released when the Activity can't find any other reference to it . This way I don't have to worry about releasing my static variables after using them.

Comment: Well, what are you worried about, in particular? As long as execution gets handed over to Activity #2, you can just clear the reference in `onCreate()`. If something goes wrong, at the very worst case, you're referencing a total of 1 bitmap which will get stuck in memory. The next time Activity #1 sets the reference, it'll get released.

Comment: I know this, just it can be an alternative solution.
Thank you again for the explanation.

Comment: No problem, have fun.